# Facebook Post-Remove URL not called when app removed

Tags: facebook

I'm testing the [post-remove URL](http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/Post-Remove_URL) call that should be pinged via POST when my Facebook application is removed, but it doesn't seem to be called.

Monitoring the network traffic in firebug and looking at the POST made when removing the app, the POST does not directly call the Post-Remove URL I specified in the app settings, nor does it pass the  POST variables I expected per the documentation.

I set up a simple output at the URL specified "remove page called" that I'd expect to see as the response but don't.

Lastly, the URL called should remove database items which do not get removed.

I don't have any evidence that my post-remove URL is getting called at all. It seems [I'm not the only one having this issue](http://forum.developers.facebook.com/viewtopic.php?id=27177) but not much insight has been provided.

Answer (score 1):

[Answer posted by folks on the Facebook Devleoper forums](http://forum.developers.facebook.com/viewtopic.php?pid=122274#p122274)